# Combining jQuery UI's draggable, selectable and droppable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to combine jQuery UI's draggable, droppable, selectable AND sortable libraries, to create a web interface for drag-selecting elements and dropping them into another area. The user will be able to remove items from the droppable area should they need to, and also control/cmd + click to select specific items without dragging.

So far I've made a pretty decent effort, but I'm having issues when it comes to adding "removed" items back into the original list of selectable items. The drag-selecting works well with these items (that are re-created dynamically), but my main problem is when control/cmd + clicking items once they have been added back to the original list.

To recreate the issue, add items to the second droppable area and then remove them (by clicking on them). Once the items are back in the original list, control/cmd + clicking the items you deleted doesn't select them properly, so when you go to drag these items, only one is added (instead of the correct amount).

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b8key7Lw/

And here's the code I'm having difficulty getting to work once the #selectable > div items are dynamically created (around line 45 in the jsfiddle):

```
$("body").on("click", "#selectable > div", function(e){
    if (e.metaKey == false) {
        $( "#selectable > div" ).removeClass("ui-selected");
        $(this).addClass("ui-selecting");
    }
    else {
        if ($(this).hasClass("ui-selected")) {
            $(this).removeClass("ui-selected");
        }
        else {
            $(this).addClass("ui-selecting");
        }
    }
    $( "#selectable" ).data("ui-selectable")._mouseStop(null);
});
```

Comment: Did you figure it out?